# Any Master Thesis Topics related to NoSQL and Machine Learning or Business Intelligence?

Tags: machine-learning, nosql

Im currently in the last year, and I want to do a masters thesis on a topic that has NOSQL and Machine Learning or Business Intelligence. In my topic i want for defintely NOSQL, so I want to add a complementary topic (machine learning or business intelligence) to it.

From my research i know that

NOSQL: provides a mechanism for storage and retrieval of data which is modeled in means other than the tabular relations used in relational databases. And there are currently 4 types (key/value, column, document and graph).

Machine Learning: is a subfield of computer science that evolved from the study of pattern recognition and computational learning theory in artificial intelligence.

So in short, for example can there be a thesis topic where i can evaluate which machine learning algorithm can be better implemented using data from a nosql database, or something like that. I would like to know your opinion.

If you can't give NOSQL related to machine learning, also NOSQL related with Business Intelligence would be a great help aswell, since Business Intelligence "is a set of techniques and tools for the acquisition and transformation of raw data into meaningful and useful information for business analysis purposes".

Comment: Perhaps you can get some ideas here: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit broad and opinion-based for StackExchange, but I'll have a quick go anyway: I don't see good topics in this area. For academic machine learning, how you store your data is largely irrelevant, either because the research is on small data anyway and will be read into memory, or because the research is pretty theoretical to begin with.

There are certainly interesting issues to explore here for distributed ML. However NoSQL stores would not in general be helpful. They specialize in random access and random updates to keyed data. ML generally needs high-throughput sequential access to data without updating it.

BI + ML is too broad. Yes there are topics in there somewhere but hard to discuss at that level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about Business Intelligence related to NOSQL, is there any topic which i can talk about? For example how business intelligence is used with nosql, can this be a topic? On the other hand, I want to compare SQL with NOSQL in regard to a complementary topic (such as for example a Algorithm implementation or for a certain kind of application use case), can you help me? @SeanOwen